# How to present a popover using Storyboards only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, storyboard

I am using XCode 6.1 and I don't have the "popover" option. Is there something wrong with my configuration? Is this normal? Have they removed it? How do I present a popover now?

This is for iPhone development, not iPad.

[image: the small view controller is to become the popover]

Comment: I think u gotta change the simulated metrics to iPad

Comment: What do you mean? I am developing for iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html)

> Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices.
>   Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

If you want to use something like a popover, you will have to use third party code for it.

Comment: Is there an alternative option for iphones? I just want to pop a uipicker wherever on the same screen. MUST I use a new UIViewController?

Comment: You could just add a UIPickerView to your ViewController's main view. Maybe animate it onscreen from the bottom or something.

Answer (score 1):

You create a UIView anyway you want and have selectors initiate it to resemble the same feel:

Take this picture for example :

[image]

The view can be made like this, notice filterView is added to the super view because i have set userInteractionEnabled to NO for the view so users are mandated to select an option before continue using the view, however, it's optional I was just pointing it out:

```
  self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
self.filterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
float X_CO = (self.view.superview.bounds.size.width - self.filterView.frame.size.width)/2;
float Y_CO = (self.view.superview.bounds.size.width - self.filterView.frame.size.height)/2;
[self.filterView setFrame:CGRectMake(X_CO, Y_CO + 75, 150, 150)];
self.filterView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.filterView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.filterView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.filterView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
self.filterView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.filterView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
self.filterView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
self.filterView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50)];
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.text = @"Select Filter Option:";
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Eurostile" size:13];
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:48/255 green:131/255 blue:251/255 alpha:1];
[self.filterView addSubview:titleLabel];

self.azButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,self.filterView.frame.origin.y/3.5,30, 30)];
[self.azButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.azButton addTarget:self action:@selector(filterButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.azButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.azButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
self.azButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
[self.filterView addSubview:self.azButton];

UILabel *azLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.azButton.frame.origin.x + 40, self.azButton.frame.origin.y, 95, 30)];
azLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
azLabel.text = @"A-Z Sort";
azLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
azLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Eurostile" size:20];
[self.filterView addSubview:azLabel];

self.zaButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, self.azButton.frame.origin.y + 40,30, 30)];
[self.zaButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.zaButton addTarget:self action:@selector(filterButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.zaButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.zaButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
self.zaButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
[self.filterView addSubview:self.zaButton];

UILabel *zaLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.azButton.frame.origin.x + 40, self.zaButton.frame.origin.y, 95, 30)];
zaLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
zaLabel.text = @"Z-A Sort";
zaLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
zaLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Eurostile" size:20];
[self.filterView addSubview:zaLabel ];

[self.view.superview addSubview:self.filterView];
```

You can add a background image to have the effect of a popover view.

Then call it at point of user touch.

Just an example is :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass: UITableView.class]) {
     //your touch was in a UITableView ... do whatever you have to do
}
}
```

and then do the same with touchesEnded: there are many other ways to go about it however. (i.e., finding exact point of contact etc. but thats up to you.

As Duncan C pointed out though, there are other freely available frameworks available to use.

Of course though, you could always create it in storyboard or xib, so many options

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said in his post, UIPopoverController objects are iPad only.

There are third party libraries that give you the same look and feel on iPhone. I don't have a specific one to point you to, but take a look on Github.

Answer (score 0):

You should see this when you Control-drag to your second VC:

[image]

When you choose "popover presentation", the resulting segue should look like this:

[image]

This option should definitely be available for iPhone, and you should be seeing it. If not, there's probably something amiss in your project settings.

It's important to note, however, that this is not the same as using UIPopoverController. Instead, it invokes [UIPopoverPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html), new in iOS 8 (I believe). Works in iPhone, and no need for 3rd party frameworks. I'm currently using it successfully in an iPhone project, so I know it works.

I believe @Daniel T.'s answer, while correct in earlier versions, has been rendered obsolete by UIPopoverPresentationController.